# Get permissions for stored procedure in sybase

Tags: sap-ase

How do I get the granted permissions for a stored procedure in sybase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the form that you want that info in.

- If you are writing SQL for some internal purpose, and you need that info as data for it, Kolchanov's answer is correct.
- If you are merely performing DBA functions, then any number of DBA GUI tools (SybaseCentral comes with the CD; DBArtisan is much better) provide that info via an explorer window and clicks

  - If you only have character based access, use
    `sp_helprotect proc_name`

[**Link to Sybase Online Manuals**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks184.htm)

Then go to: Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.5/Reference Manual: Procedures, nd follow the explorer.

Answer (score 3):

If I wanted to check the permissions for object "whatever_[table|procedure]", I would run the following query:

Example for "whatever" being a table

```
Displaying result for:
---------------------
select permission = a.name
from master.dbo.spt_values a
   , master.dbo.spt_values b
   , sysprotects p
   , sysobjects  o
where a.type = "T"
and   a.number = p.action
and   b.type = "T"
and   b.number = (p.protecttype + 204)
and   o.id = p.id
and   o.name = 'whatever_table'

permission                   
---------------------------- 
References                   
Select                       
Insert                       
Delete                       
Update                       

5 Row(s) affected
```

Example for "whatever" being a stored procedure

```
Displaying result for:
---------------------
select permission = a.name
from master.dbo.spt_values a
   , master.dbo.spt_values b
   , sysprotects p
   , sysobjects  o
where a.type = "T"
and   a.number = p.action
and   b.type = "T"
and   b.number = (p.protecttype + 204)
and   o.id = p.id
and   o.name = 'whatever_procedure'

permission                   
---------------------------- 
Execute                      

1 Row(s) affected
```

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.5 > Reference Manual: Tables > System Tables

sysprotects

sysprotects contains information on permissions that have been granted to, or revoked from, users, groups, and roles.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1550/html/tables/X16615.htm